# Windows 10 build 1909 - Corrupt Store - DISM version from 1903

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, dism, windows-10-v1909

Anyone shed any light on this. I've been looking at an issue with a windows 10 machine 1909 build 10.0.18363.720, where after windows updates are installed including KB4560960 (2020-06 Cumulative Update) and KB4497165 (2020-01 Update for Windows 10 1909 for x64 based systems) the machine fails to load and enters a windows repair and fails. A system restore is run back to the last restore point and it boots again.

I've run SFC /Scannow and it found some errors that it was able to fix. I also ran a DISM /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth and it reports that the component store is repairable.

When I try to run restorehealth it cannot find the sources. I've tried mounting an ISO and using that as the source as well to no avail.

I have noticed however, that DISM is Version 10.0.18362.1, where as the Image Version is 10.0.18363.720

For convenience, Build 18362 is 1903 and 18363 is 1909 (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/)

As far as I am aware the machine should have been installed from 1909 install media as I was built and put into place in Jan this year.  It appears though that it may have been installed with 1903 and upgraded to 1909 based on the DISM version number.

Is this normal for 1909 (I guess not as my windows is on 2004 and DISM shows the same version as the image version, and that was upgraded from 1909)

When I can my hands on the machine physically (I'm working remotely on it presently) I'll use the a USB key with 2004 on it to upgrade it (Upgrading via windows update to 2004 also fails).

I am interested to know how this occurred and/or if it can be easily fixed otherwise?

Thanks
Andy.

Comment: You cannot use a 1903 ISO to repair a 1909 installation.  If the upgrade to 2004 from Windows Update fails, I can guarantee you, that it will fail from the ISO.  You have to determine the cause of the upgrade failure to perform the upgrade.  You should download a 1903 ISO and use DISM to repair your installation.  10.0.18362.1 is 1903 not 1909

Comment: I was using the 1909 ISO for it not a 1903 ISO. 

I checked with a Colleague that is still using version 1909. Their DISM reports a version of 10.0.18362.900 and an Image version of 10.0.18363.900. 

The build on the machine that has the problem is version 1909 (10.0.18363.720).

Comment: @AndyPelton Yes, It is same for me, MS may not have changed DISM version in 1909. I am on windows version 18363.636 while DISM version is 18362.1. I am unable to upgrade to 2004 using iso. Did you got successful in upgrading?